# I'm Stalking You, What am I

Tags: riddle, word

I'm smart and can see you.

You can hear my voice entangled in your mind.

You lift me up in your fear, happiness and excitement.

By day and night I'm always near you.

Comment: From the title: a stalker? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a

> Smartphone?

I'm smart and can see you.

> It's 'smart' and has cameras on the front and back

You can hear my voice entangled in your mind.

> Siri, google assistant etc, plus lots of people use headphones, projecting the phone's sounds directly into their heads.

You lift me up in your fear, happiness and excitement.

> Everyone documents everything, holding phones up in front of them to record things

By day and night I'm always near you.

> Always in a pocket, a bag, on a nightstand etc...

Title - I'm stalking you:

> Several leaks in the last few years have revealed various intelligence agencies' capacity to track people through smartphone usage, to say nothing of the location histories that the manufacturers themselves have.

Answer (score 1):

Is it -

> OUR MIND (BRAIN )

I'm smart and can see you.

> Mind is smart it can see us in mirror through our eyes

You can hear my voice entangled in your mind.

> Our mind can speak to ourselves .

You lift me up in your fear, happiness and excitement.

> Our mind talks to our selves in fear, happiness and excitement telling what to do next telling us what to do ? thus helping or lifting us ..

By day and night I'm always near you.

> Our mind is always with us .

I'm Stalking You, What am I

> Our mind always watches my views , whom I talk to , and what I hear ..

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> My brain?

I'm smart and can see you.

> The brain is responsible for intelligence and sight.

You can hear my voice entangled in your mind.

> Hearing yourself think

You lift me up in your fear, happiness and excitement.

> You head (mind) perks up during fright, happiness, and excitement

By day and night I'm always near you.

> Your good ol' pal brain never leaves you

Answer (score -1):

Is it a ...

> smart phone because it is smart and I lift it up and fear sounds like ear.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**)  How does your answer add to the identical ones already given? You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.